# Simple regex question (vim search/replace)

Tags: regex, vim, vi

How do I specify that there are several options for a string in a search?
For example, I want to find any combination that start with either `jspPar`, `btn` or `jspAtt` that ends with the letter `K`.

Also - I need to replace it with a string depending on the original prefix.
for example, if the prefix was `jspPar` I need to replace it with the letter `P`. (and, let's say, `B` and `A` for `btn` and `jspAtt` accordingaly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is

```
\(jsPar\|btn\|jspAtt\)[^ \t]*K
```

what you are looking for?

The `\(jsPar\|btn\|jspAtt\)` says “at this point, match any of these alternatives”, then `[^ \t]*` says “at this point, match any amount (incl. zero) of space or tab characters”, and `K` of course means “at this point match a K”.

---

For your added question *could* do something like this:

```
%s/\(jsPar\|btn\|jspAtt\)[^ \t]*\zsK/\=submatch(1) == 'jsPar' ? 'P' : submatch(1) == 'btn' ? 'B' : 'A' /g
```

(The `\zs` says “consider the match to have started at this point” so only the “K” will be replaced.)

But I would only do that if I *had* to do the substitution in a single pass. Otherwise I’d just run three `s///`s:

```
%s/jspAtt[^ \t]*\zsK/A/g
%s/jsPar[^ \t]*\zsK/P/g
%s/btn[^ \t]*\zsK/B/g
```

Given command history, that’s much less typing, and is also very unlikely to require debugging, whereas that’s always a potentiality when specifying any computation.

Comment: The ORs need to be escaped, I believe. \|

See http://www.softpanorama.org/Editors/Vimorama/vim_regular_expressions.shtml

Comment: Yeah, already fixed. I can never remember which non-Perl regexp dialect requires me to escape them or not.

Comment: anything about my addition to the question?